# Is there a predictable order when scanning/scrolling an elastic search index?

Tags: elasticsearch, scroll, database-scan

When scanning an ElasticSearch index it is not possible to apply any sorting according to the [documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type.html).
But is there any definition at all about the order of the results during this process? If yes, is it predictable?

Background info:

I need to do operations on 5M documents regulary, each batch of 1.000 docs taking about 1 minute to be processed. As I cannot make sure that the process will be finished each time it is ran, I would love to make it pick up its work where it has been interrupted last time, e.g. if it the scroll result was sorted by `ID` (I know, it is not), I would keep track of the last processed `ID` in my code, and with the next run no longer process any document with `ID <= lastProcessedId`, to make sure that every document gets processed regularly.

Btw: by "processing the document" I do not mean writing additional info back to the index, rather updating some other stuff in my database. Writing a timestamp to the indexed document would not help in my case, since one of the reason for the process being interrupted could be that the index is replaced with a fresh index (re-built from scratch).
Writing a processed timestamp to the database is also not a desired option for me, because the iteration performance is the reason why I am using the index to scroll in the first place....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the sort order is not predictable. I was going to suggest using timestamps, but then I read the rest of your question :)

Really, the only way to make a scanned search "resumable" is to divide your docs into tranches on some field, eg timestamp or ID, and to use a range query to scroll through just one tranche at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this... I will probably revert to iterating over the database, since the main benefit of iterating over the index (super fast iteration) would not longer apply when doing range queries....